# Is it required to remove `pollInterval` from `getLastUpdate` response?

Tags: sonos

I am updating an old Sonos service that currently returns `pollInterval` as part of its `getLastUpdate` response. In the current Python self-test, this causes failures. According to the [docs](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/87), this parameter is deprecated.  The service has been around for a long time and, if possible, we'd like to leave it in if it's safe. Is it required to remove this parameter from the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pollInterval` was removed from our `getLastUpdate` API and was marked as deprecated as it was not being used by our player.  Leaving it in will not cause any harm.

As of our next release (currently in Beta) we will be re-introducing the pollInterval field.  You may keep it in, but be aware that with the next release we will be responding and changing the polling interval that we use to call `getLastUpdate` dynamically.